# Using the filter() with NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

I have tried filtering out values in a list by using the filter- function `filter()`

In a Video from Socratica they explained by using `None` you can filter out `False` boolean values.

e.g.

Input:

```py
z = filter(None, ["", 6, "", 0, 12, "", -5])
for element in z:
    print("True:", element)
```

Output:

```py
True: 6
True: 12
True: -5
```

As you can see all values which have the boolean value of `False` are filtered out...

But if I try to filter out the list with a method which has the same functionality, it does something completely different.

Input:

```py
def test(a):
    if a == None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
z = filter(test, ["", 6, "", 0, 12, "", -5])
    
for element in z:
    print("True:", element)
```

Output:

```
True: 
True: 6
True: 
True: 0
True: 12
True: 
True: -5
```

As you can see the value 0 is also included in the output, not like in the first variant of filtering out `False`boolean types. Why is this the case?

PS: For me it is fully comprehendable, that `None` objects have no value. Then why is it the case that 0 is not included in the results of the first variant of filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `None` argument to `filter()` has the same effect as using the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) as the filter function. `bool(object)` returns `False` if the object [has a False value in a boolean context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). The function uses `None` as a *signal value*, a way to tell the function to filter the elements based on their boolean value instead of using a given function.

It is *not* a test if something is equal to `None`.

Your input elements are never equal to `None`:

```
>>> "" == None
False
>>> 0 == None
False
```

Because `"" == None` is *False*, your function returns `True` for all your inputs.

The `bool()` function returns the expected `False` value for empty strings or `0`:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> not bool(0)
False
```

so `filter(bool, ["", 6, "", 0, 12, "", -5])` only lets `6`, `12` and `-5` through:

```
>>> for result in filter(bool, ["", 6, "", 0, 12, "", -5]):
...     print("True:", result)
...
True: 6
True: 12
True: -5
```

If you wanted to put that into a function using `if`, just have the `if` statement do the truth testing:

```
def test(a):
    if a:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but, this is just a more verbose spelling of the `bool()` function.

On a separate note: you should never use `== None` to test for `None`, because `None` is always the same, single object, the correct way to test for it is to use `is None`. This is a faster operation.